# Unit testing angularjs $watch in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, watch

I'm pretty new to `AngularJS` and even newer to unit tests in `Jasmine`. I have to write a test for:

```
$scope.$watch(
function () {
    return alertService.getAlert();
},
function (newVal, oldVal)
{
    if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.alert = alertService.getAlert();
    }
});
```

`getAlert` returns things like:

```
[ Object({ type: 'typeOfAlert', message: 'alertMessage' }) ].
```

Now, I've learned (in some cases even understood) things about digest, timeouts, mocking services etc. but I only know how to handle variable-fired watches and I'm not sure what to do with:

```
alertService.getAlert();
```

Could anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after two days I found my mistake. Just needed to inject service in

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$timeout_, _alertsService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('mainPageController', {
        '$scope': scope
    });
    alertService = _alertService_;
}));
```

and test whole thing with

```
it('should fire getAlerts when alert is appended', function(){
    alertService.appendAlert('success', 'TESTMESSAGE' );
    alertService.getAlert();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.alerts).toEqual([
        Object({ type: 'success', message: 'TESTMESSAGE' })
    ]);
})
```

It feels embarassing now, but I hope someone has same problem in the future.